# regex pattern replacement in python/jinja

Tags: python, regex

New to regex and I'm having difficulty putting together a regex argument for this custom function `re_replace` in python:

```
{{fieldname|re_replace(pattern, replacement)}}
```

The pattern uses regex and I'd like to return the following `id=0123456` where the fieldname follows the format below:

https://a.website.com/page.php?id=0123456&variable1=abcde123&variable2=abc123de

I've managed to replace the `id=0123456` but haven't been able to do the inverse.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you show the code for the custom function and the attemps at regex you've tried. also if you just want to get a value from fieldname why do you need the replace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you use [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search) rather than your own custom function to do this?

The syntax would be:

```
re.search(r'id\=\d+', fieldname).group(0)      # return 'id=0123456'
re.search(r'(?<=id\=)\d+', fieldname).group(0) # return '0123456'
```

*To do the inverse operation you could use [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub).*

Comment: Hi, sorry I can't get the code above to work.  It's for a jinja2 template if that makes any difference.  http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/

webpage.php?{{re.search(r'id\=\d+', {entry.url}).group(0)}}

Comment: shouldn't the syntax be `{{re.search(r'(?<=id\=)\d+', fieldname).group(0)}}`, that is double brackets around the variable/calculated thing... what did you try?

Comment: Tried the above and got `Template Syntax Error: expected token ',' got 'string'`

Comment: @user1681032 Try setting this as another variable in python (and giving jinja access to that), so it's: `{{just_the_id}}`

Comment: @user1681032 perhaps `{{fieldname|lambda x: re.search(r'id\=\d+', x).group(0)}}` works... but I think doing it in the .py is preferable.

Comment: thanks hayden, found a solution to create the variable in python

Comment: I don't think you can just call a python function directly in your jinja2 template.  But it's easy to expose a function to jinja, e.g. in your Python code, call `jenv = Environment(...)` then `jenv.filters['yourfilter'] = lambda s: re.sub('pat','repl', s)`.  Now in your template you can do `{{fieldname|yourfilter}}`.  You could even expose `re.sub` as a filter directly, just need to wrap it so that the target string is the first argument, and pattern/replacement are keyword args.

Answer (score 0):

Look into named capturing. That way you can do something like this:

```
(?P<name>...)
```

And use the **match.groupdict()** and return a named dictionary containing the matches.
Read more about it here: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html